# Update latest "Datetime"

Tags: php, sql

How should my query look like, if i'd like to `UPDATE` only the last Datetime record? I have `stamp_in` & `stamp_out` in my table.

With my query I update all fields in `stamp_out` with `$datetime_now`.

With PHP I am filtering this down to only update the day of "Today". But, if there is several records the same day, all records get updated! How do I solve this?

**PHP**

```
$query = "UPDATE usr_time_reg
          SET usr_stamp_out = :datetime_now, usr_stamp_status = :usr_stamp_status
          WHERE usr_stamp_in LIKE :date_now";
          //LIMIT LATEST usr_stamp_in
```

Comment: Have you tried `LIMIT 1` with `ORDER BY usr_stamp_in DESC` ?

Comment: You need to find a way to pick the latest item if there are several records. If it is important to remove the latest item, store timestamp instead of date.

Comment: @jarhl I cannot use timestamp, because the servertime doesnt match my GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right query should be:

**PHP**

```
$query = "UPDATE usr_time_reg
          SET usr_stamp_out = :datetime_now, usr_stamp_status = :usr_stamp_status
          WHERE usr_stamp_in LIKE :date_now
          ORDER BY usr_stamp_in DESC LIMIT 1;
```